# C# WPF Button Enable/Disable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button which is:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStylePermit1}" 
 Click="permit1_Click" x:Name="permit1" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

and in my .cs code I also have a `int floor = 1;`

I want to be able to enable the button if the floor = 2 and disable the button if not. What is the best possible way to do this?

Comment: You can use an `if`/`else` statement, or `permit1.IsEnabled = (floor == 2);`.

Comment: see also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849265/commandbinding-question-how-to-enable-command-button

Comment: Maybe you can update the question to show the button xaml (so to check the binding), the datacontext setup and the Floor property to see the INotifyPropertyChange implementation. That will help identifying why the code is not working

Answer (score 0):

in your .cs code, create a method that either disables or enables the button, then call that method whenever floor changes value. So a simple way to achieve that is to create a Public Property on floor member, and use the property to change the value of floor as well as to change the enabled property of you button.

```
private int floor;

public int Floor{
    get { return this.floor;}
    set { 
        this.floor = value; 
        if (this.floor == 2)
        { this.permit1.Enabled = false }
        else {this.permit1.Enabled = true}     
    }
}
this.Floor = 1;
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this? Because I have many buttons like this one for different floors?

Comment: Sure there are different ways of doing this. But in the end if buttons are suppose to enable/disable independent of each different floor, then you stille need to create that logical link between floor Property and the related button. Do you have more code snippets of the view and code behind? then it would be easier understand what you are working with here.

Answer (score 0):

Two solution are provided as follows:

1. Straight Forward idea:

   if (floor == 2) permit1.IsEnabled = true;
   else permit1.IsEnabled = false;
2. Ternary

   permit1.IsEnabled = (floor==2) ? true : false;

You can try the following XAML code as an example:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Button x:Name="permit1" Content="Test" Width="200" Click="permit1_Click" IsEnabled="False" Background="Red"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Press here" Width="100" Click="Button_Click"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

And the MainWindow.xaml.cs includes the following C# code:

```
int floor;
    Random random01 = new Random();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void permit1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         //your code here
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        floor = (int)Math.Round(random01.NextDouble(), 0) + 1;
        Button1.Content = floor;
        permit1.IsEnabled = (floor==2) ? true : false;
        /*
        if (floor == 2)
            permit1.IsEnabled = true;
        else
            permit1.IsEnabled = false;
        */
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `permit1.IsEnabled = (floor==2) ? true : false;` ? You can use simple `permit1.IsEnabled = floor==2;`.

Comment: @Arci, YES! You are correct. I just want to give an example of Ternary for Cutie.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF typical way for handling this would be to use [data binding with value convertor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data)

Here is a quick look at the changes you will need to do:

In your xaml you will bind your control's `IsEnabled` property to `Floor`

```
<Button  Content="Click Me!" Click="button_Click" 
x:Name="permit1" IsEnabled="{Binding Floor, Converter={StaticResource  converter}}">
```

`Floor` is an `int`, while `IsEnabled` is the `bool`, to link these you need the converter, I have put in the converter as a windows resources so that it can be used for multiple different objects (in the same class, but you can put it in a central resource.xaml file).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FloorToEnableConverter x:Key="converter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

For the framework to be able to find your property `Floor` it should be in the datacontext of the XAML, I have done this in the code behind constructor

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

You will need to define the logic for this converter in your own class, which is just the implementation of `IValueConverter` interface

```
 public class FloorToEnableConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("value cannot be null");

                if ((int)value == 1)
                    return false;
                if ((int)value == 2)
                    return true;

                // for all other values disable
                return false;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
}
```

Finally when the property changes you will need to notify the UI about the changes, so this needs to be implemented by `INotifyPropertyChangeInterface`

I have implemented this on my demo class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

And the actual code is:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int floor;
        public int Floor
        {
            get { return this.floor;}
            set { this.floor = value;
                // The string here should exactly match the property name
                OnPropertyChanged("Floor"); }
        }
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
```

This should work, also even though in this example I have implemented the code for change notification in the code behind class, in WPF try to avoid using the code behind class, that was a required in win forms, but WPF provides alternate mechanism for this. Have a look at the [MVVM pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/) for a better way to structure the code.

Comment: Would this also work for other buttons for example if the floor = 1, will it enable it?

Comment: Yes, it will work for each button with respect to the floor property you bound it to. The converter class is shared, so if you want the conversion logic to be different for each floor then you might need to create more convertors.

Comment: Once you have setup the INotifyPropertyChange and created a convertor, you just need to setup the binding properly in the xaml for this to work for various buttons

Comment: I tried implementing this code but the button is still enabled when I change floors.

Comment: switch (((ListViewItem)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Name)
            {
                case "Ground":
                    imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\1.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    floor = 1;
                    break;
                case "Second":
                    floor = 2;
                    imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\2.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;

Comment: That's how I change the value of my floor

Comment: You need to change the property "Floor", look at the INotifyPropertyChange interface, it raises an event when property value is changed. Also ensure that the data context is setup as the XAML binding will use the datacontext to determine which property to bind.